# How can I get my Android app to show a random string from an xml document string-array?

Tags: java, android

I'm new here and to Android, so if I'm doing anything wrong please let me know.

I've been googling for help on this and I really can't find anything.

My app crashes on launch and I can't figure out why!

Anyways, here's my facts.xml containing a string-array of all the facts I'm trying to make it show on the app.

```
<string-array name="factsArray">
    <item>BONUS: This app was developed by 3 guys in a school!</item>
    <item>A single bolt of lightning contains enough energy to cook 100.000 pieces of toast.</item>
    <item>Neptune was discovered in the year 1846, and it didn't complete an orbit until 2011.</item>
    <item>If you drilled a tunnel straight through the Earth and jumped in, it would take you exactly 42 minutes and 12 seconds to get to the other side.</item>
    <item>The human brain takes in 11 million bits of information every second, but is only aware of 40.</item>
    <item>A red blood cell can make a complete circuit of your body in 20 seconds.</item>
    <item>The strongest creatures on Earth are gonorrhea bacteria. They can pull 100,000 times their own body weight.</item>
    <item>Polar Bears are nearly undetectable by infrared cameras, due to their transparent fur.</item>
    <item>The temperature on the surface of Mercury exceeds 430 degrees Celcius (806 Fahrenheit) during the day, and, at night, plummets to -180 degrees Celcius (-292  Fahrenheit)</item>
    <item>A total solar eclipse only happens once every one and a half years.</item>
    <item>Butterflies taste with their hind feet, and their taste sensation works on touch – this allows them to determine whether a leaf is edible.</item>
    <item>Saturn has 150 moons.</item>
    <item>The Appollo astronauts' footprints on the moon will probably stay there for at least 100 million years.</item>
    <item>To make 1 pound (453.6 grams) of honey, bees would have to visit more than 2 million flowers.</item>
    <item>Honey is the only food that doesn't spoil.</item>
    <item>Mona Lisa does not have any eyebrows.</item>
    <item>The farthest objects we can see in space are 47 billion light years away.</item>
    <item>The largest giant squid ever recorded was 43 feet (13.1 meters) long.</item>
    <item>It would take 1,200,000 mosquitoes, each sucking once, to completely drain the average human of blood.</item>
    <item>A black bear can run 35 mph (56.3 km/h)</item>
    <item>A small percentage of the static you see on 'dead' TV stations is left over radiation from the Big Bang.</item>
    <item>As of this app's creation, there are 6 people in Space.</item>
    <item>If you were to remove all of the empty space from the atoms that make up every human on earth, the entire world population could fit into an apple.</item>
    <item>25% of the US would flood if melting glaciers caused sea levels to rise by 32 feet.</item>
    <item>To know when to mate, a male giraffe will continuously headbutt the female in the bladder until she urinates. The male then tastes the pee and that helps it determine whether the female is ovulating.</item>
    <item>A koala bear sleeps 22 hours during a single day, which is the amount of time it needs to digest its food.</item>
    <item>The Earth spins at 1,000 mph (1,609 km/h) but it travels through space at 67,000 mph (107,826 km/h)</item>
    <item>Every second around 100 lightning bolts strike the Earth.</item>
    <item>If you could drive your car straight up you would reach space in just over an hour.</item>
    <item>When a flea jumps, the rate of acceleration is 20 times that of a space shuttle during launch.</item>
    <item>One million, million, million, million, millionth of a second after the Big Bang the Universe was the size of... a pea.</item>
    <item>The tallest three ever was an Australian eucalyptus - in 1872 it was measured at 435 feet (132.59 meters) tall.</item>
    <item>An electric eel can produce a shock of up to 650 volts.</item>
    <item>In 5 billion years the Sun will run out of fuel and turn into a Red Giant - after swallowing the entire solar system!</item>
    <item>A pig's orgasm lasts for 30 minutes.</item>
    <item>The low frequency call of the humpback whale is the loudest noise made by a living creature. The call can be heard from 500 miles (804.672 km) away.</item>
    <item>Bent is our best teacher!</item>
</string-array>
```

And my MainActivity:

```
package com.clement.sciencefacts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

// import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }
    // Attempt at making the random array
    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] factArray = res.getStringArray(R.array.factArray);
    public int factNumber = factArray.length;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int fact = rnd.nextInt(factArray.length);
    // Make buttons do stuff.
    public void factBttOnClick(View v) {
        TextView factBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factBox);
        factBox.setText(factArray[fact]);
    }
    public void creditsOnClick(View v) {
        TextView factBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.factBox);
        factBox.setText("Programmers: Martin Schultz & Jonas Clément \nIcon designer & third wheel: Nikolaj Kristensen \n\nThe facts come from random knowledge that we had from the Internet! :-D \n\nThere are currently /*+factNumber+*/facts in the app!");
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me on this one? Thanks in advance!

Edit: Updated my MainActivity with my current code, still crashes.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want to get good answers to your question, it will help a lot to do a lot more legwork up front, and provide a lot more details on what you've already done to try to solve the problem. "I'm having trouble, please do this for me" questions don't often get a lot of traction. If you're having errors or problems with something crashing, you'll need to provide a lot more details on what's going wrong, including full error messages. Otherwise, there's not enough information for anyone to go on in giving you help.

Comment: ^ Indeed. Can you include the stack trace you're getting? Also, cleaning up the code by removing large blocks of commented code makes it easier for people to read which means more and better answer.

Comment: Thanks :) Sorry I don't understand the lingo, what's a stack trace? I'll remove the blocks of commented code now.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change this line:

```
factBox.setText(fact);
```

to that:

```
factBox.setText(factArray[fact]);
```

because this: `int fact = rnd.nextInt(factArray.length);` is an index you get, not an array value

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I changed the line and it still crashes on launch. Can I generate a log of sorts that you can use?

Comment: @user3583016 log cat messages aren't helping to get any clue about the crash. Look for the red lined messages